# Create Calculated table based on slicer selection

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I've a table with ID, Names and Day column as under :

```
+----+------+-----------------+
| ID | Name |      Days       |
+----+------+-----------------+
|  1 | A    | 30 days or less |
|  1 | A    | 30 days or less |
|  1 | A    | 30 days or less |
|  1 | A    | 31 to 60 days   |
|  2 | B    | 30 days or less |
|  2 | B    | 31 to 60 days   |
|  2 | B    | 61 to 90 days   |
|  2 | B    | 61 to 90 days   |
|  3 | C    | 90+ days        |
|  3 | C    | 61 to 90 days   |
+----+------+-----------------+
```

Alongside I've two slicers, coming from two different tables with such one column each

[image]

What I'm trying to do here is, based on the user slicer selection, I want the table to be filtered and only output "Name" that arent present in the first slicer selection, also the anti-join needs to be done on the ID column

So for the above slicer selection, viz. 30 days or less compare with 31 to 60 days, the results should be a table with column "Name" and just record "C" as its the only Name thats not present in the "30 days or less"  but present in "31 to 60 days"

Comment: In your sample data, C is not present in "31 to 60 days".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found mismatch in your explanation as you said C is there in "31 to 60 days" but actually C is not present in "31 to 60 days" in your sample data. Despite the above confusion, I tried ti figure out the process based on your explanation ignoring your sample data mismatch. If I am close to understand correctly, you can try this below steps and also can adjust things if your requirement is bit different.

**Step-1:** Create 2 different Iceland (non relational) table with same value belongs to your slicer. Both table will have the same value, but you just need to create 2 slicer from 2 tables and make sure there are no relation as shown below-

[image]

**Step-2:** Create this below measure-

```
show_hide = 

VAR current_name = MIN('your_base_table_name'[Name])
VAR selected_range_1 = SELECTEDVALUE('day range 1'[range])
VAR selected_range_2 = SELECTEDVALUE('day range 2'[range])

VAR chk_not_in = 
IF(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            ALL('your_base_table_name'),
            'your_base_table_name'[Name] = current_name && 'your_base_table_name'[Days] = selected_range_1
        )
    ) = 0,
    1,
    0
)

VAR chk_in = 
IF(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            ALL('your_base_table_name'),
            'your_base_table_name'[Name] = current_name && 'your_base_table_name'[Days] = selected_range_2
        )
    ) = 0,
    0,
    1
)


RETURN IF(chk_not_in = 1 && chk_in = 1, 1, 0)
```

Here below is the output of measure-

[image]

**Step-3:** Now just add the newly created measure to the Visual level filter as below and you will get your expected set of data in the table visual based on your slicer selection.

[image]

Comment: this is perfect ! and yes, I messed up my earlier table where C had to be in the "31 to 60 days" range

I'm kind of new to PBI so can you elaborate on why you had to define the VAR current_name = MIN('your_base_table_name'[Name]) and then add it to the filter

Thanks

Comment: Also, would there be a way to get the total count of all themismatching values?
I mean the sum of show_hid where its 1 ?

I was also wondering how did you manage to get those buttons to select the days, I use a chicklet and its nots as appealing

Comment: Var current-name i used to keep the current row name in it. I measure, it works row one by one. So when it is in row N, the variable will keep the name of row N. Further I have used that variable to find all rows from the table for the name stored in that varible.

Comment: To get the count, you may conver the measure code for a custom column. Then you can create a measure with SUM for the newly created custom column to get the count.

Comment: Finally, for the slicer styling - select slicer type Horizontal from the properties window.

Comment: I tried adding custom custom usng the same formula for measure but it throws an Eof error, would really appreciate if you could let me know if custom columns accept assigning or variables and if the formulas are different from measures

Comment: From first variable, remove the MIN and try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221647/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-user11845701).